# import cv2 import os cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create() cascadePath = "haarcascade_frontal

Tags: python, opencv, keras, operating-system, artificial-intelligence

I tried to run the program, but it displays the error result as above, Has anyone experienced this error before? here is my code :

```
import cv2
import os

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()

cascadePath = "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
```

Comment: question does not include any error message. include the full traceback and all relevant code. please review [ask] and [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this one can help you
looks like you forgot to add this command :

```
import cv2
import os

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()

cascadePath = "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascadePath);
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

path = 'trained/'
```